# Ask a question without using the letter e

Tags: wordplay, knowledge

How do I ask to:

> leave work early

without using the letter `e`

Comment: You could say: "I quit."

Comment: Can I go prior to my daily hours?

Comment: May I plas lav work arly? [imagine emoji raspberry face here]

Answer (score 10):

For something a bit longer:

> Boss, nothing in my load is still outstanding, so can I go for today? You can call if anything crops up!

Answer (score 5):

There is no 'e' in this question.

> "May I go now?"

Answer (score 4):

> I'm going now,so f*** you all.

If you really aren't keen on work....

Comment: There is an e in asterisk though.

Comment: That was not an asterisk.... that was a star !

Comment: In retrospect, I think this is the funniest answer to the question.

Answer (score 3):

You could say

> Can I clock out soon?